# In MATLAB, I want to specify the type of scatter markers based on an array.

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, I want to specify the type of scatter markers based on an array.

For example:

```
x = [1 5 3 7 2];     % x data
y = [6 3 7 4 1];     % y data

c = [1 1 2 1 2];     % colors
s = [2 1 2 2 1];     % shapes

scatter(x,y,30,s,c)
```

But that's too many arguments. It works for just `c` (color) but how can I specify marker type  (and color) like this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do would be to separate your data by marker type and then call scatter twice: once for each marker type. 
For example:

```
ssq = ( s == 2 )
xsq = x( ssq );
ysq = y( ssq );
csq = c( ssq );
scatter( xsq, ysq, 30, csq, 's');
hold on;
scirc = ( s == 1 )
xcirc = x( scirc );
ycirc = y( scirc );
ccirc = c( scirc );
scatter( xcirc, ycirc, 30, ccirc, 'o');
hold off;
```

This is the most elegant solution I can think of. It would be nice if MATLAB allowed you to specify a vector of marker types like you can for color.

Comment: There's no need to use `find`. Just put `xsq = x(s==2);` and so on, and they will work faster.

Comment: @Yvon - I agree.  Also, to save time, simply compute what indices you need once: `s1 = s == 1; s2 = s == 2; xsq = x(s1); ysq = y(s1); csq = c(s1);`, etc.

Comment: Thank you all! Any idea how to add a legend for this showing the four different combinations of c and s? @rayryeng